# NSSortDescriptor for ordering to-many sets of objects having a property of NSString?

Tags: core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have a `NSManagedObject` class `recipe` that has a to-many relationship to `ingredient`. Each  `ingredient` has a property called `name` (NSString).

I want to sort the `recipe`s by the `name` of the `ingredient`s, so that a `recipe` with any `ingredient` starting with the letter 'a' should be put before any `recipe` that has all of its `ingredient` starting with 'b', 'c' and so on.

Example:

```
cookie recipe    <->> { 'chocolate', 'sugar', 'more sugar' }
apple pie recipe <->> { 'sugar', 'apples' }
```

should sort the 'apple pie recipe' before the 'cookie recipe', because the pie has one of its  ingredients' names starting with the letter 'a'. The cookie `recipe` has 'c' as its lowest ingredient starting letter.

What's the correct way an `NSSortDescriptor` should look like for this?

Comment: This is a sorting task, not a predication task.